# How to have diferent markers and line styles while plotting same variable from multiple data files?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

How can I have diferent markers or line styles when I am plotting same variable from 8 diferent data files in one figure?
I have got my code that reads multiple excel files and it is perfectly fine with plotting the variable I call for from all 8 diferent excel files.
Although I already have the plot with different colors that I have defined. However, somehow, I cannot define any marker or diferent Line Styles. I have attached my plotting codes below; please also see the [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsTf5.png)

```
ax = gca;
grid on;
hold on
plot(Pin_dBm,Pout_Meas_dbm,"LineWidth",2)
%ax.LineStyleOrder={'-o','-+','-*','-x','-s','-d','-v','->'};
ax.ColorOrder=[1 0 0; 1 0 1; 0 1 0; 0.4660 0.6740 0.1880; 0 0 1; 0.3010 0.7450 0.9330; 0.8500 0.3250 0.0980; 0.9290 0.6940 0.1250]
ylabel('Output Power [dBm]','Color','K')
xlabel('Input Power [dBm]')
title('Output Power comparison - ON mode (0V)', 'Color', 'k')
legend('3F50Sa1','3F100Sa1', '5F50Sa1','5F100Sa1','7F50Sa1','7F100Sa1','9F50Sa1','9F100Sa1','location', 'bestoutside')
```

Comment: (1) plot each line separately, change marker and linestyle each time or (2) obtain the output of the plot function, which is an array of plot handles, and modify properties on those handles.  Usually (1) is easier.

Comment: @XZhang Hi, thanks for the comment. but it is impossible to plot each line separately as they are not different variables from one data file. they are same variable from different data files. this means in different line plotting's I would get 8 plots of same variable from one data file. and the second way I have no clue hoe to do it.

Comment: oooh it's surely possible.  You will find so many ways to go from "same variable from different files" to "different variables". I'll leave that as an exercise though...

Comment: If you're currently plotting a matrix with several columns, you can just `hold on` instead, and use a `for` loop to plot each column of that matrix... You need to [edit] your question to turn your code into a [mcve] to show representative variables if you expect us to fully understand what you're working with. Also please read the tag descriptions before using them, this question has nothing to do with `matplotlib` (which is Python-related) or `matlab-guide` (which is for building user interfaces)

Comment: @Wolfie thanks for the comment, yes you are right, I am new to this but learning, thank.

Comment: Just an update, I copied my own question with same detail from here and pasted somewhere else and received a good enough help to sort my issue out with some adjustment. I just needed to make a for loop for it. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change trace (or marker) properties you have to use the plot handle, not the figure handle, to change line properties like `LineWidth` and `Color`.

To grab the plot handle you have to plot like this

```
hf1=figure(1)
ax = gca;
grid on;
hp1=plot(Pin_dBm,Pout_Meas_dbm)
hp1.LineWidth=2
hp1.Color='r'   % red
```

..

`hf1` is the figure handle, not the trace or curve or graph handle.

The figure is the frame containing traces.

You don't have to, this is ok

```
hf1=figure
```

but it's good practice to number figures `figure(n)` as soon as generated, it helps reading code if later on someone has to findout what figure handle belongs to what `figure`.

now you tell the graph container, the figure with handle `hf1` not to remove the 1st trace regardless of what you plot next:

```
hold(ax1,'on')
```

and now, with a for loop or one by one, or in any other way you choose, you can add more traces onto same figures changing the properties you choose using a different plot handle

```
hp2=plot(Pin_dBm2,Pout_Meas_dbm2)
hp2.LineWidth=1.5
hp1.Color='b'   % blue
```

..

and as you mention in your question you can send the same variable updated with different input data or file

```
update_Pin_dBm;
update_Pout_Meas_dbm;
```

If you do not update Pin_dBm and-or Pout_Meas_dbm the next plot with different properties may be identical or similar and overlap the previous trace.

```
hp3=plot(Pin_dBm,Pout_Meas_dbm)
hp3.LineWidth=1
hp1.Color=[0 1 1]    % cyan
```

The figure handle `hf1` could still be used to change trace properties, because as the container to the plot, has as children property the handle to the plot. But no one uses what is otherwise a rather long Java-like expression

Note: The term marker is generally used, not for the graph line, the plot, but for the pointers on the graph line that scopes and also MATLAB allows to put, to read a particular `(x,y)`.

If you find this answer useful, would you please be so kind to accept it?
Thanks for reading my answer.

Comment: Thanks, for your explanations, John. Yes, the for loop was the answer and as it was multiple files so a for loop defined to read multiple files so same counter should be used to have markers on each variable from each data file. Thanks again.